# why after_add in rails 5 is executing method without an object is being created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am not able to understand why `after_add` is executing method before object is being created.

Suppose I have a class `User`

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_subjects, after_add: :create_user_subject

  def create_user_subject(user_subject)
    UserSubject.create!(user_id: self.id,......) 
  end
end
```

So when I am trying to create user object.

```
user = User.new(name: 'some name')
user.save
```

then it is throwing an error

```
OCIError: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("user_subjects"."user_id")
```

Why it is trying to save an association `subjects` before `user` object is created. It was working in `rails 3` why the functionality is changed in `rails 5` and what are the alternatives. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The after_add callbacks is triggered when an item is added to a collection. So it only works when adding the association via the `<<` .

Instead of it, you can use:

- `after_create` (works only once - after save record to the database)
- `after_save` (works every time when you save the record, even after update action)

Answer (score 0):

`subjects` table contains a foreign key called `user_id`, which establish association to the `users` table.

To create a `subject` belonging to a `user`:

```
user = User.new(name: 'some name')
subject = user.books.build(name: "some name"....)
```

`user.save` will create record in `users` as well as `books` associated with the user

Comment: @BrahamShakti Does this not help you?

Comment: @Gabbar I tried but I failed, I cannot understand what Op want through my answer's chat.